# Reading data from Excel files in C#.net

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, sqlbulkcopy

I am reading an excel file in my application & then data is being modified & copied to another worksheet in the same excel file. Now, when I tried reading data from the newly created excel file in order to save it in the database using sqlbulkcopy, it is throwing following oledb exception "external table is not in the expected format"

any pointers will be really appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: how are you copying the data from one sheet to the second one? Can't you save the data from memory to the database instead of saving it to the second sheet and then trying to store from second sheet into database?

Comment: @davide - my requirement is to modify the data in the excel sheet while uploading & then display it in the table to user so that users can map the columns to fields in the database. After this, I will upload the data into database.

Comment: Posting a little code may help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to read data.

```
public static System.Data.DataRowCollection ReadDataFromFile(int tabIndex = 0)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(excelFileDir + excelFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Auto-detect format, supports:
            //  - Binary Excel files (2.0-2003 format; *.xls)
            //  - OpenXml Excel files (2007 format; *.xlsx, *.xlsb)
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                // Choose one of either 1 or 2:

                // 1. Use the reader methods
                do
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // reader.GetDouble(0);
                    }
                } while (reader.NextResult());

                // 2. Use the AsDataSet extension method
                var result = reader.AsDataSet();
                return result.Tables[tabIndex].Rows;
                // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
            }
        }
    }
```

and then read columns via index

```
rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
```